# Python Area of triangle - At least one of the sides will be parallel to the x or y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x

Came up with the following but can't seem to figure out why in some cases i'm getting a negative number:

```
def getTriangleArea(x, y):
    area = ( (x[0]*(y[1]-y[2])) + (x[1]*(y[2]-y[0])) + (x[2]*(y[0]-y[1]))) / 2
return int(area)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you think of a way in which the subtraction of two numbers could result in a negative number?

Comment: possibilities would include when the signs of the numbers are different or we're trying to subtract a larger number from the smaller number.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a Python/code question. It's a math problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the absolute value of the area.

```
def getTriangleArea(x, y):
    area = ( (x[0]*(y[1]-y[2])) + (x[1]*(y[2]-y[0])) + (x[2]*(y[0]-y[1]))) / 2
    return abs(int(area))
```

Comment: Yep that's it, thank you.

Comment: Don't use `int`, just return `abs(area)`. The area of a triangle is not necessarily an integer. Quick example: `x, y = [0,1,0], [0,0,1]` will give an answer of 0 with this method, while the answer should be 0.5.